# Sonarlint automatic triggering is always off?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

Current using version 2.3.1 of the sonarlint plugin on Intellij IDEA 2016.2.3. Connected to a remote sonar server.

This may be a known bug, but I can't seem to get the automatically triggered analysis to work. I click the checkbox and save the settings, but it never works. When I go back to the settings the checkbox is "magically" unchecked once again.

Is there something that would prevent this feature from being enabled? The manually triggered analysis still works fine, but errors aren't caught 'on-the-fly'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bug [SLI-106](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-106), fix coming in SonarLint for IntelliJ v2.3.2 .

Comment: I suppose the downvote comes from the fact that this is an existing bug. I did search current bugs, but must have passed SLI-106 by because it is about the triggering being stuck on, not off. It makes sense that this is the same issue though. Marking as answered. Hope it does indeed fix my issue.

Comment: No clue where the downvote comes from. The fix is in Release Candidate already, you can try it out here: [SonarLint-2.3.2-RC1.zip](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-intellij/releases/download/2.3.2-RC1/SonarLint-2.3.2-RC1.zip)